# First time using @media screen

Tags: html, css

It did not go so well ... The right sidebar disappears if screen is small alright but the top sidebar is staying there and I do not understand why ... after fiddling for hours I decided to ask for help.

```
<html><head>  
<style type="text/css">
body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
background-color:#aaa;
font-family:trebuchet ms, tahoma;
}

@media screen and (max-width:899px){
div.sidebar{visibility:hidden};
div.sidebartop{visibility:visible};
div.mainbox{width:100%;top:calc(100% - 210px);min-height:calc(100% - 210px);}
}

@media screen and (min-width:900px){
body{font-weight:bold};
div.sidebar{visibility:visible};
div.sidebartop{visibility:hidden};
div.mainbox{width: calc(100% - 310px);top:0px;min-height:100%;}
}

div.sidebar{
position:fixed;
right:0px;
height:100%;
z-index:2;
background-color:#9374a4;
width:300px;
color:#fff;
margin:0px;
padding:15px;
box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
border-left:1px solid pink;
}

div.sidebartop{
top:0px;
position:fixed;
z-index:2;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:15px;
box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
height:200px; 
background-color:#abab63;
}
</style></head><body>
<div class="sidebartop"></div><div class="sidebar"></div>
</body></html>
```

Please assist me ... thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your HTML here as well. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What exactly do you require ? Is the sidebar  supposed to stay?

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: Also, you should use `display: none` vs `visibility: hidden`. using visibility keeps the element's space, but just hides it, where as display "removes" the element from the document flow.

Comment: Media queries should come _after_ the actual classes, so changing `div.sidebar` in media query doesn't do anything if the actual definition of said class comes after the media query. Think of media queries as breaking the current state. If you set the sidebar to be `visible`, then use a media query to hide it at a specific width.

Comment: I wanted a sidebar if the window's width is big enough and a top 'sidebar' if it's not ie. on mobile - see website ... the code's apparently working but the top sidebar is being troublesome

Comment: @Chell you must post your HTML here. Posting a link to your website is not appropriate, as once you made the fix, it basically renders this question useless to future visitors. As I posted in the first comment, post the minimum amount of code that replicates your issue.

Comment: @disinfor Thanks and sorry I'm new I didn't know websites weren't recommended ... but I did post the minimum amount of code to replicate the error ... basically insert it in an empty html file with two <div> each of one of these two classes - sidebar and sidebartop - and you'll see the yellow sidebar stays no matter the sizing of the window ...

Comment: @Chell No, you did not post the minimum amount of code. It's not our job to create your HTML. Edit your question with the HTML...your question will probably stop getting downvoted if you do that.

Comment: Its better now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if the screen is "big" you have side bar and no top bar, if the screen is small you have topbar and no sidebar, right?
I think you confused visibility:visible with display:none and display:inline-block and also create a parent for the main and side div.
Try this:

```
<html><head>  
<style type="text/css">
body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
background-color:#aaa;
font-family:trebuchet ms, tahoma;
}


@media screen and (min-width:900px){.sidebartop{display:none}}

@media screen and (min-width:900px){body{font-weight:bold}}


.mainbox{display:inline-block;width:70%;min-width:600px}

.sidebar{
position:fixed;
right:0px;
height:100%;
z-index:2;
background-color:#9374a4;
width:300px;
color:#fff;
margin:0px;
display:inline-block;
padding:15px;
box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
border-left:1px solid pink;
}
@media screen and (max-width:899px){.sidebar{display:none}}

.sidebartop{
top:0px;
position:fixed;
z-index:2;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:15px;
box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
height:200px; 
background-color:#abab63;
}
</style></head><body>
<div class="sidebartop"></div>
<div>
<div class="mainbox"></div><div class="sidebar"></div>
</body></html>
```

I did not try all the compatibly it is just a tutorial example

Comment: Hi Massimiliano and very sorry I did not answer before ... busy week so I did not work on it but it's perfect. I'm still trying to figure out my mistake but whatever you did is right. Thanks so much